# Union of two affine varieties equals to the product of the varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am confused about this equation in algebraic geometry:
$$
\mathbb{V}(I)\cup\mathbb{V}(J)=\mathbb{V}(IJ)
$$
I have proved that $\mathbb{V}(I)\cup\mathbb{V}(J)\subseteq \mathbb{V}(IJ)$, but I don't know how to prove $\mathbb{V}(IJ)\subseteq \mathbb{V}(I)\cup\mathbb{V}(J)$. Specifically, I don't understand why if $f(x)\neq 0$ for some $f$, $f(x)g(x) = 0$ implies that $g(x) = 0$. Since $f,g\in \mathbb{A}^n$, isn't it possible that $f(x) = (1,0,1)$ and $g(x) = (0,1,0)$ and $f(x)g(x) = (1\times 0, 0\times 1, 1\times 0)$ which yields to $(0,0,0)$?

Is $f(x)g(x)$ defined the same way as that of the direct product of rings?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a big misunderstanding here - functions take values in $k$ here, so you get one number out, not a tuple of numbers.

Comment: *Hint:* $k$ is a field and so has no zero divisors.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you!! So that's why we don't care about additional structures of $\mathbb{A}^n$ can every function takes a value in $\mathbb{A}^n$ and evaluates to a value in $K$.